# how can I stop my Arduino code after 1 second?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, timing

I want to send message NRF24L01 to NRF24L01. I want to see if I can send just one second. How can I stop code after 1 second?

Comment: study the example code that is included with the arduino IDE

Answer (score 0):

You can use different ways:

**Use `setup` only**

Instead of putting code in the `loop` function,  put it in `setup`, which is only executed once (use a `for` loop to send around 1 second.

**`millis()` excluding `setup`**

It is better to use the `millis` function and compare it against the start of sending; when 1 second is reached, don't send anything or use an infinite `while` loop.

Use something like:

```
unsigned long time_start;

void setup()
{
    // Your normal code 

    time_start = millis();
}

void setup()
{
    if (millis() - time_start >= 1000) 
    {
        while(1) {};
    }

    // your normal code (which should not take many ms,
    // otherwise the above code is not reached.
```

**millis() including `saetup`** (Thanks to Edgar Bonnet):

```
 void loop()
 {
     if (millis() >= 1000)
     {
        while(1) {};
     }
 }
```

This will stop exactly after 1 s  after startup (excluding the `setup`). It will start counting after `millis` start counting, which is before the `setup` function.

Actually, in none of the above the Arduino 'stops', it just is doing endlessly nothing (well internally endlessly checking against the `true` condition which never changes).

Comment: Or even `if (millis >= 1000) exit();`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks, I added it to the answer.